# Blindspot Anagram Clues

Tags: blindspot

I read [this](http://tvline.com/2016/04/25/blindspot-season-1-episode-titles-anagrams-clues/) article a while back that said that from episode 11 to episode 23 of blindspot the titles of the episodes will be anagrams with a hidden message. (Previous titles were anagrams too but they weren't a sequential message)

And in the first comment of that article someone had decoded them as well. They go as follows:

1. Woe Has Joined = Who Is Jane Doe
2. A Stray Howl = Taylor Shaw
3. Eight Slim Grins = The Missing Girl
4. Bone May Rot = Or Maybe Not
5. Split The Law = The Past Will
6. Cede Your Soul = Cloud Our Eyes
7. Sent On Tour = Trust No One
8. Persecute Envoys = Suspect Everyone
9. Authentic Flirt = Lift The Curtain
10. Evil Handmade Instrument = Unveil The Mastermind
11. Cease Forcing Enemy = In Case Of Emergency
12. Scientists Hollow Fortune = Follow These Instructions
13. Erase Weary Youth = Stay Where You Are
14. Rules In Defiance = Find A Secure Line
15. Older Cutthroat Canyon = To Contact Your Handler
16. Any Wounded Thief = Find What You Need
17. Mans Telepathic Loyal Lookouts = In Almost The Last Place You Look
18. One Begets Technique = To Begin The Sequence
19. In The Comet Of Us = Focus On The Time
20. Swift Hardhearted Stone = Then Head First Road West
21. Of Whose Uneasy Route = To Your New Safehouse
22. If Love A Rebel, Death Will Render = The Final Order Will Be Revealed
23. Why Await Life’s End = When It’s Filed Away

So what does the secret message mean?

Comment: The results of the *second half*'s titles (11-23) spell out a message that's supposed to lead you to a secret phone number. See if you can make heads or tails [**of this**](http://www.ew.com/article/2016/05/23/blindspot-scavenger-hunt-nbc).

Comment: https://blindspot.fandom.com/wiki/Anagram - As it's an ongoing thing, there is no answer yet.

Comment: @JohnP - Now the show has finished, it might be worth turning that link into an answer